# How to sum ID within a DF by area in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataframe of crash statistics called crashes_TA. The datafame looks like the following but on a much larger scale with each row representing a crash.

The dataframe is called crashes_TA

| TA_name | TA_code | fatal_count | serious_injury_count | minor_injury_count | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grey | 061 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Buller | 062 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Grey | 061 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| Clutha | 063 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| Clutha | 063 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| Otago | 064 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 6 |

I would like to summarise fatal, serious, and minor by TA_name by creating a new column called casualties. I would also like to summarise ID which represents the number of crashes per region as this value would be different to casualties as not all crashes have casualties. This new column would be called crashes

My new dataframe would then look like this:

| TA_name | TA_code | fatal_count | serious_injury_count | minor_injury_count | casualties | crashes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grey | 061 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 2 |
| Buller | 062 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| Clutha | 063 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 2 |
| Otago | 064 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |

This is my code I have tried so far

```
crashes_stats_TA <- crashes_TA %>% 
  group_by(TA_code, TA_name) %>%
  summarise(across(contains("count"), ~sum(., na.rm = T)),
            across(Population, ~mean(., na.rm = T),
            across(contains("perc"), ~mean(., na.rm = T), .names = "{.col}_mean"))) %>%
  mutate(casualties = round(fatal_count + serious_injury_count + minor_injury_count), 
         crashes = round(ID = sum(ID, na.rm = T)))
```

However, when I do this I get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Crashes`.
i `Crashes = round(ID = sum(ID, na.rm = T))`.
x object 'ID' not found
```

[image: dataframe]

Comment: you cant assign a variable inside `round`.  replace `crashes = round(ID = sum(ID, na.rm = T))` with `crashes = round(sum(ID, na.rm = T))`

Comment: Shouldn't `Buller` `causalities` ouptut be `3`. In your expected output it is `1` ?

Answer (score 2):

We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(TA_name, TA_code) %>%
  add_count(name="crashes") %>% 
  summarise(across(contains("count"), sum),
            causalities = sum(fatal_count, serious_injury_count, minor_injury_count),
            crashes= unique(crashes))
```

```
  TA_name TA_code fatal_count serious_injury_count minor_injury_count causalities crashes
  <chr>     <int>       <int>                <int>              <int>       <int>   <int>
1 Buller       62           1                    1                  1           3       1
2 Clutha       63           1                    2                  3           6       2
3 Grey         61           3                    1                  2           6       2
4 Otago        64           1                    1                  0           2       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(TA_name, TA_code) %>%
  summarise(across(fatal_count:minor_injury_count, sum, na.rm = TRUE),
            crashes = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(casualties = rowSums(select(., fatal_count:minor_injury_count)))

#  TA_name TA_code fatal_count serious_injury_count minor_injury_count crashes casualties
#  <chr>     <int>       <int>                <int>              <int>   <int>      <dbl>
#1 Buller       62           1                    1                  1       1          3
#2 Clutha       63           1                    2                  3       2          6
#3 Grey         61           3                    1                  2       2          6
#4 Otago        64           1                    1                  0       1          2
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(TA_name = c("Grey", "Buller", "Grey", "Clutha", 
"Clutha", "Otago"), TA_code = c(61L, 62L, 61L, 63L, 63L, 64L), 
    fatal_count = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), serious_injury_count = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), minor_injury_count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L), ID = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
out <- aggregate(.~ TA_name + TA_code, df[setdiff(names(df), "ID")], sum)
out$casualties <- rowSums(out[, -(1:2)])
```

-output

```
> out
  TA_name TA_code fatal_count serious_injury_count minor_injury_count casualties
1    Grey      61           3                    1                  2          6
2  Buller      62           1                    1                  1          3
3  Clutha      63           1                    2                  3          6
4   Otago      64           1                    1                  0          2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(TA_name = c("Grey", "Buller", "Grey", "Clutha", 
"Clutha", "Otago"), TA_code = c(61L, 62L, 61L, 63L, 63L, 64L), 
    fatal_count = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), serious_injury_count = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), minor_injury_count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L), ID = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```